# Creating a List<String> in Android Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, list, dynamic, for-loop

I'm building an android application where I need to create a simple list of String items, which i will then add a specific control for each item in the list.

This is the list I want to create:

```
List<String> projects = new List<String>(); // How?
```

The code I was trying:

```
String projects = new string[] { "hey","yo","app","xamarin","c","xaml" };
```

I need to count the items, something like this:

```
int amount = projects.Count(); // Can I do this?
```

Then adding the controls for each item in the list

```
// Add the tiles, one by one
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
  // Inflate the tile
  var tile = LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.Tile, null);

  // Set its attributes
  tile.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.projectName).Text = currentProject;

  // Add the tile
  projectScrollView.AddView (tile);
}
```

"currentProject" string is retrieved from SharedPreferences, just haven't got that far yet

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @HighCore Sounds like question is about syntax

Comment: It's about how I can create a basic list of strings, adding, reading and removing the items easily and being able to count them

Answer (score 6):

```
   var projects = new List<String>() { "hey","yo","app","xamarin","c","xaml" };
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this code, but "List" isn't found. Just get an error. What import/using is it?

Comment: System.Collections.Generic;

Answer (score 3):

if you are using the array to store what values you want in your list use the foreach

```
List<string>project = new List<string>();
string[] projects = { "hey","yo","app","xamarin","c","xaml" };

foreach(string str in projects)
{
   project.Add(str);
}
for (int i = 0; i < projects.Length; i++)
{
  // Inflate the tile
  var tile = LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.Tile, null);

  // Set its attributes
  tile.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.projectName).Text = currentProject;

  // Add the tile
  projectScrollView.AddView (tile);
}   

// you can get items from your list by using  project.Count, your List<string> instead of projects.Length your array and take information from your list and output your tiles that way
```

Comment: Except, no, you should use `.AddRange` and avoid the loop and array resizes.

Comment: But the List<String> isn't detected when I type it. Do I need to add a "using" line?

Comment: What are your "using" right now? hard to say if you have it there if it is unknown.

Comment: `List<T>` is part of `System.Collections.Generic`

Answer (score 1):

To initialize a `List<string>` with `collection initializer` use the below syntax.

```
List<String> projects = new List<String>(){"hey","yo","app","xamarin","c","xaml"};
```

`Count` is not a method it is a property. You need property syntax.

```
int amount = projects.Count;
```

Comment: Can't you leave off the `new List<String>()`? I know the parens at least are extra.

Comment: @Magus yup, that's optional. but I believe it will create an array not list. Except parenthesis rest is required

Answer (score 0):

```
int amount = projects.Length;
```

that is how you can set the value of the int. It doesnt appear that you are populating your list with that code.